# Crystal Report for Income and Expense wth opening and closing balance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I need the output attached using mssql and display in crystal report

I have tables name Income, Expense, Expense Details HeadMaster.

Table Structure

**HeadMaster**

     HeadMasterId

     Name

**Income**

     IncomeId

     HeadMasterId

     IncomeDetails

     TxnDate

     Amount

**Expense**

     ExpenseId

     HeadMasterId

     ExpDetails

     TxnDate

     Amount

**ExpenseDetails**

     ExpenseDetailsId

     ExpenseId

     CenterId

     Amount

I have written 3 querys 
**1. Income Details**

```
SELECT TxnDate, Name AS Particular, Amount FROM Income I INNER JOIN HeadMaster
HM ON HM.HeadMasterId = I.HeadMasterId WHERE TxnDate >= '2014-02-01 00:00:00' AND
TxnDate <= '2014-03-15 23:59:59' ORDER BY TxnDate
```

**2. Expense Details**

```
SELECT TxnDate, Name AS Particular, Amount FROM Expense E INNER JOIN ExpenseDetails 
ED ON ED.ExpenseId = E.ExpenseId INNER JOIN HeadMaster HM ON 
HM.HeadMasterId = E.HeadMasterId WHERE TxnDate >= '2014-02-01 00:00:00' AND 
TxnDate <= '2014-03-15 23:59:59' ORDER BY TxnDate
```

**3. Opening Balance**

```
DECLARE @Expense NUMERIC(8,2)
DECLARE @Income NUMERIC(8,2)
DECLARE @Balance NUMERIC(8,2)
SELECT @Income = SUM(I.Amount) FROM Income WHERE TxnDate < '2014-02-01 00:00:00'
SELECT @Expense = SUM(I.Amount) FROM Expense WHERE TxnDate < '2014-02-01 00:00:00
SET @Balance = @Income - @Expense
SELECT @Balance AS OpeningBalance
```

How can Merge the query output to resemble my required output in Crystal Report? 
Also Can I merge this query's into one single query?

I am using Visual Studio IDE 2012 for Win App using C# and Crystal Report.

Output should look like these[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the multiple queries.. you can do the required operation in crystal report itself.

1. Since you have `Income` and `Expences` separately. Take a main report and in that main report place 2 sub reports side by side in detail section.
2. In sub report1 take the information of `Income`. Take all the required tables while making connection and link those tables in `Links Tab` of Database Expert.
3. Similarly in second sub report take `Expences` tables and follow the same process to link the tables.

[Link1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiIl7Shir9k) and [Link2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/designer/Understanding_Databases5.html) to know how to link the tables.

4.Now in both the sub reports make groups as following:

```
Group1: Sub report1 `Income`..
        Sub Report2  `Expences`
```

5. Now create 2nd group in both the sub reports as following:

```
Group 2: Sub Report1: Date
         Sub Report2: Date
```

6.Now create 3rd group in both sub reports as following:

```
Group 3: Sub Report1: Balance
         Sub Report2: Balance
```

7.In details place the fields `Date`, `Particulars` and `Amount` and take the summary in group footers as required.

8.To get exact output as screenshot draw `lines` between the `columns`

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Can I merge all the queries into one single query?

Comment: I am not sure whether you can merge all queries into single query in crystal report.. You can write a query in crystal report but sure whether you can merge multiple queries or not.

Comment: Can you provide how to use Sub Report Total in Main Report?

Comment: found this solution useful for above query [link](http://www.harindaka.com/2008/10/crystal-reports-how-to-share-data.html)

Comment: You are welcome.....Take a shared varaiable in sub report and store the value that need to be passed there and in the main report use the same shared variable as it is you will get the value....