# Add multiple Dataset programatically for subreports VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, crystal-reports-2010

I have facing problem while showing crystal report with 2 subreports. Both subreports pulling data from stored procedure.

All working fine on design time. But at runtime, Crystal Reports has an error saying table not found (second table) and nothing is displayed in reports.

This is the similar problem that I want to solve -
[Crystal Report for Income and Expense wth opening and closing balance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23402940/5829253)

This is my code - both stored procedure has a single parameter of `datetime` type:

```
    Dim DOF As Date = #4/1/2016#
    DOF = Format(DOF, "dd/MM/yyyy")

    Dim DOT As Date = #4/1/2016# ' Now.Date
    DOT = Format(DOT, "dd/MM/yyyy")

    Dim DS As Data.DataSet
    Dim DA As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim s_Sql As String
    Dim s_sql2 As String
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    s_Sql = "sp_DailyIncome"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(s_Sql, o_con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FDate", Format(DOF, "MM/dd/yyyy")))

    DA = New SqlDataAdapter
    DA.SelectCommand = cmd
    DS = New Data.DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS, s_Sql)
    cmd.Dispose()

    s_sql2 = "sp_DailyExpense"
    o_Cmd = New SqlCommand(s_sql2, o_con)
    o_Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    o_Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FDate", Format(DOF, "MM/dd/yyyy")))


    DA.SelectCommand = o_Cmd
    DA.Fill(DS, s_sql2)


    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New rptDailyCashReport
    rptDoc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("SchoolName").Text = "'" & holdSchoolName & "'"
    rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@FDate", DOF)

    rptDoc.Subreports.Item(0).SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))
    rptDoc.Subreports.Item(1).SetDataSource(DS.Tables(1))

    Dim objForm As New ShowReport
    objForm.ViewReport(rptDoc, , "")
    objForm.ShowDialog()
```

and this is the error:
[image: Error in Runtime]

Comment: You are not filling the DS1 dataset, yet you are assigning it as the  datasource of your subreport

Comment: Please help me to get this problem solved. As per your comment, how to correct my code? @F0r3v3r-A-N00b

Comment: check if SP sp_DailyExpense exist. May be typo.

Comment: It exists at server side. No typo error. I also checked that Dataset DS has both tables in vb code.

Comment: Are you setting the database of your report at design time to stored procedure? Try setting the data source to XSD, then use a datatable as datasource via code and this is how I open a subreport. `Dim mainReport As <Name of your report with crpt extension> Dim subReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument subReport = mainReport.OpenSubReport(<name of your subreport as defined in your main report>) mainReport.SetDataSource(<your main report's datatable>) subReport.SetDataSource(<your datatable>)`

Answer (score 0):

this is how I open a subreport.

```
Dim mainReport As <Name of your report with crpt extension> 
Dim subReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
Dim subReport2 As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument 
subReport = mainReport.OpenSubReport(<name of your subreport as defined in your main report>)
subReport2 = mainReport.OpenSubReport(<name of your second subreport as defined in your main report>)
mainReport.SetDataSource(<your main report's datatable>)
subReport.SetDataSource(<your datatable>)
subReport2.SetDataSource(<your datatable 2>)

reportViewer.ReportSource = mainReport
```

or from your code

```
Dim rptDoc As New rptDailyCashReport
Dim subReport1 As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
Dim subReport2 As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

subReport1 = rptDoc.OpenSubReport(<name of your sub report 1>) '<-- !! NAME IS CASE SENSITIVE
subReport2 = rptDoc.OpenSubReport(<name of your second sub report>)

subReport1.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))
subReport2.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(1))

' place this at the last part, before showing your report
rptDoc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("SchoolName").Text = "'" & holdSchoolName & "'"
rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@FDate", DOF)

Dim objForm As New ShowReport
objForm.ViewReport(rptDoc, , "")
objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I think problem is starting with 2nd Subreport at Runtime. I debugged my vb code and it clearly shows that my dataset has two different tables. If I removed one subreport from crystal report and its related code. It start showing data at runtime (Means one subreport is showing from any of the two)

Comment: If you have multiple subreports, you must declare a variable for each subreport and also assign a datasource for each of them. See my updated answer

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but not worked for me.  Below is link for Screnshot of debug screen.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ov6zrs6eKCbTZhcFFXQ24zQUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: same problem, same old error (as shown in image in question)

Comment: Can you show your updated code? Also post a screenshot of your report definition, including subreports

Comment: I can send u my entire project. give me your email. @F0r3v3r-A-N00b

Comment: Sorry. can't do that

Comment: Thanks everyone for giving valuable suggestion here. It helped indirectly to me solving this problem.